# MySQL calculation for rainfall

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with MySQL query. Basically to simplify it:

I have a table with meteorological data from a weatherstation. One of the measured parameters is rainfall. I have managed to get the calculations to a form where I have one column with days (1 Feb, 2 Feb, 3 Feb etc.) and second column, which gives the daily rainfall for that particular day (0, 3.5, 14.2 etc.).

Now what I want to do next is calculate the longest dry and longest wet period. In other words, the longest period where there is 0 rainfall on consecutive days, wetperiod being the exact opposite - most consecutive "non-zero" days.

In the output I want to have - the number of days in the period, starting date and end date. So basically two variables, lets say dry_count, dry_date, which I would then transform into an output such as: "Number of days: dry_count, dry_date".

I initially had it as two variables (dry_start and dry_end), but that didnt work, because in case there are two occassions for example where there is the same longest period, I would then want it as eg. 3 Feb - 5 Feb, 8 Mar - 11 Mar - so the date needs to be in the end saved as one variable and if it is not null, then it would add a comma and the other period.

I tried various things but wasnt successful. The data is extracted on a PHP site from a MySQL database, so I am getting the results in a while statment, row after row. Any help please? I hope I explained it ok.

Comment: You need to show us the sample data, what you've tried, and the desired result.

Comment: Can you post the queries you have tried?

Comment: What exactly do you want: calculae the Number of dry dates and the last dry-date day (the date being the begining of that dry period) on the PHP side?

Comment: OK, here is how I get the data:
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT Logdatetime, TodayRainSoFar
FROM alldata 
GROUP BY YEAR(Logdatetime), MONTH(Logdatetime), DAY(Logdatetime)"
 );

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
/*here I need to do the calculations, variable Logdatetime is the date, variable TodayRainSoFar gives the amount of rainfall in mm*/
}

Comment: I sympathize, I feel SQL lacks a function which returns the primary ID of the record which has the MAX value. Probably needs a subselect.

Comment: calculating the number of drydates is easy, but I need to find the longest "dry period" - most consecutive zero days, and output as number of days in that period and when it occured (start date - end date), if it occured more than once, than obviously all the periods, separated by comma or whatever symbol

Comment: How many days worth of data are you going to be examining, and how often a day is it going to be accessed?  Do you remotely gather the information each time the page is loaded, or do you have a local store that you keep old data in and you just update it every day or so with the new rainfall data?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to save this new data about wet periods and dry periods back into the rows, to save for later use?

I assume this is so that as each new day is added, it's easy to re-calculate .... or because the data is moving onto somewhere else?

Anyway, if this is the case, then one way you could go about it is by having two new columns:  'wet_count" and "dry_count".  Count through each row.  If the row's wet/dry value matches that of the day before, then increment that value.  If it doesn't, zero the values and set the appropriate one to the new value.  As such:

```
day       rainfall    wet_count    dry_count
Feb 1     1           1            0
Feb 2     0.5         2            0
Feb 3     0.75        3            0
Feb 4     0           0            1
Feb 5     0           0            2
Feb 6     0           0            3
Feb 7     0.5         1            0
Feb 8     1.25        2            0
Feb 9     1.5         3            0
Feb 10    3.5         4            0
Feb 11    4.5         5            0
```

Then you can simply pull the max value from the table, go back to the first 1 in that column prior to that date, and you have your 'largest period' and 'when it started'.

On each new day's data, you only need to calculate versus the previous day, then run two very simple database searches to get the new 'largest period'.

More specifically - you pull the distinct values of 'wet_count', ordered descending, and take only the first answer.  You do a select on the database where all wet_count = that max, or 1. and you get the number of wet periods that match that particular value, plus the possible start dates.  The 1 immediately prior to the max value will be the start date.

Comment: Hi, now actually I only want it as an output on that particular site, no changes in the db, so this wouldnt probabl work

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I think correlated subqueries provide the best approach in MySQL for this type of question.  The idea is to find the first day with rain after a day without rain, and to use this for grouping purposes.  Then the min and max of the group provide the boundaries of the dry spell.

Here is the idea:

```
select min(date) as FirstDate, max(date) as LastDate,
       (max(date) - min(date) + 1) as DrySpellDays
from (select t.*,
             (select date
              from t t2
              where t2.rainfall > 0 and
                    t2.date > t.date
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as NextRainDate
      from t
      where t.rainfall = 0
     ) t
group by NextRainDate
```

The calculation for wet days in a row follows the same structure, but with the logic reversed:

```
select min(date) as FirstDate, max(date) as LastDate,
       (max(date) - min(date) + 1) as DrySpellDays,
       sum(t.rainfall) as TotalRainFall
from (select t.*,
             (select date
              from t t2
              where t2.rainfall = 0 and
                    t2.date > t.date
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as NextDryDate
      from t
      where t.rainfall > 0
     ) t
group by NextDryDate
```

Comment: Sorry, I just started working with MySQL 2 months ago and dont really now too much about it. How would I integrate this into my db? The table is called "alldata", variables "Logdatetime" and "Todayrainsofar".

Comment: @user2370078 . . . Replace `from t` with `from alldata` in the two places it occurs in each query and change the column names to match what is in the database.

Comment: and one more thing, What do I do in the end, how do I get the desired output, in other words what variable gives the dates and number of days to display?

Comment: @user2370078 . . . `t2` is called an alias and is a fundamental part of the SQL langauge.  The variables are the names in the `from` clause.  My recommendation is that you need to learn SQL before you start trying to use it for querying databases.

Comment: so how would I then get output for example "3 days, DateX to DateY"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP unoptimized attempt. Note: this is untested, I just typed it in here, don't have anything to test on, don't have a paper to rethink this to do better so lots of improvement possible.

```
$dry_date = NULL;
$dry_length = 0;
$wet_date = NULL;
$wet_length = 0;

$current_date = NULL;
$current_length = 0;

$dry_flip = false;
$wet_flip = false;
// assume you get "select date, rainfall from rainfalltable"
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // if rainfall is zero we do dry_day calculation
    if ($row['rainfall'] == 0) {
        // two options here - we already started counting or this is a new streak of dry days
        if ($dry_flip) {
            // if we already started, it's simple
            $current_length = $current_length +1;
        } else {
            // if we didn't start counting, let's reset the counter. 
            if ($wet_flip) {
            // First check the wet status - maybe we were counting it so let's save
                $wet_flip = false;
                if ($current_length > $wet_length) {
                    // since we got the longer streak, we update wet status
                    $wet_date = $current_date;
                    $wet_length = $current_length;
                }
                $current_date = NULL;
                $current_length = 0;
            }
            $current_length = $current_length + 1;      
            // One more thing to do         
            if ($current_length == 1) {
                $current_date = $row['date'];
            }
        }

        } else {
        // two options here - we already started counting or this is a new streak of dry days
        if ($wet_flip) {
            // if we already started, it's simple
            $current_length = $current_length +1;
        } else {
            // if we didn't start counting, let's reset the counter. 
            if ($dry_flip) {
            // First check the wet status - maybe we were counting it so let's save
                $dry_flip = false;
                if ($current_length > $wet_length) {
                    // since we got the longer streak, we update wet status
                    $dry_date = $current_date;
                    $dry_length = $current_length;
                }
                $current_date = NULL;
                $current_length = 0;
            }
            $current_length = $current_length + 1;      
            // One more thing to do         
            if ($current_length == 1) {
                $current_date = $row['date'];
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Additional note: better use the MySQL query if you can.

Comment: hmm tried it but the date varibles return empty values and the number is always 0 :(

Comment: Did you change the $row['date'] and $row['rainfall'] to match your column names?

Comment: but I actually just managed to solve it... using about 10 chained IF and ELSE IF statements :D

I drew it on a paper, all the different possibilities, like a mindmap and from there I went step by step and it actually works :)

Thx a lot anyway

Comment: I guess the lesson of the day is that you always draw on paper, so you're clear with what you want to do, before starting programming :)
That lesson is golden, I'd say. I always try to draw stuff on the paper first - first to get a clear look of what I want, then list out all the options and stuff (algorythm), check if there are tools that do that already and THEN I may start programming :)

Comment: "Bad programmers worry about the code. Good programmers worry about data structures and their relationships." - Linus Torvalds